# Theories with only positive helicity particles have a trivial S-matrix

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, helicity

How to prove and explain statement from [What is the Simplest Quantum Field Theory?](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1446) (page 8):

> **Theories with only positive helicity particles have a trivial S-matrix**

It isn't quite clear, because:

1. In standard perturbative technic one start with Lagrangian and after construct possible vortexes and study Feynman diagrams, but unfortunately I have never face with such Lagrangian
2. It's not clear, why this result don't depend on Lagrangian form

Comment: Please try to give enough context so that answerers know where you're coming from - What is the source of this statement? Why do you think it is true?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I added link

Comment: 1. When you cite a source, it would be nice if you gave the exact location of the quote in the source and some surrounding context, especially that this is about supersymmetric theories. 2. The argument for this statement is discussed in the very paper you link, in particular section 2.2. What exactly about the paper's argument is unclear to you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, it is not special about SUSY. But second section about SUSY. About on-shell susy. My question about general QFT

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but perhaps a step in the right direction. From the perspective of the Lagrangian, we can decompose operators into helicity-specific parts. Taking Yang-Mills type theories as an example, we know that we should build an action out of $F_{\mu\nu}$ for it to be gauge invariant. The operators we can include are of the form

$$
F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}, \epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}, F_{\mu}^{~\nu} F_{\nu}^{~\rho} F_\rho^{~\mu},...
$$

Hitting these with the Infeld–van der Waerden symbols, we can expand them explicitly into their different helicity parts:
$$
F_{\mu\nu}\sigma^{\mu}_{A\dot{B}}\sigma^{\nu}_{C\dot{D}} = F_{A\dot{B}C\dot{D}} = \frac12\left(\varphi_{AC}\epsilon_{\dot{B}\dot{D}} + \epsilon_{AC}\bar{\varphi}_{\dot{B}\dot{D}}\right),
$$
where $\varphi$ ($\bar{\varphi}$) is the positive (negative) helicity piece.

It seems like it's difficult to construct a gauge-invariant theory with vertices with only one type of helicity. This probably isn't true in dimensions other than four though...

If I get time I might update this answer if I think of anything.